# datepicker of cf7 not working in firefox

Tags: wordpress, datepicker

I am a plugin called **contact form 7** for *contact us* page. I have date picker in it. It is not working in firefox but  working in chrome. How can I fix this error ? Can anyone the solution for this problm ?

Comment: if you right-click and inspect element with chrome on the page where it should show up, do you get an error in your console?

Comment: it is not working in firefox. but there are no errors in console.

Comment: sorry i read it wrong, i posted an answer . The issue involves html5

Answer (score 7):

The answer from @Christophvh was right but incomplete. The datepicker calendar is here but not visible. There seams to be a bug in the jquery datepicker that sets an incorrect `z-index` value thus making the calendar hidden behind the form.

Here is how I made it work :

1) Enable WCF7 fallback but putting this code snippet in your theme `functions.php` file

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' );
```

2) Fix the bug by putting this code snippet in your theme `functions.php` file, or by editing you theme CSS if you know how to :

```
add_action('wp_head', 'replacethiswithyourthemename_wcf7_datepickerfix');
function replacethiswithyourthemename_wcf7_datepickerfix(){
    ?><style>#ui-datepicker-div {z-index:99!important;}</style><?php
}
```

Comment: I am using a child theme and just used the parent theme name.  Unfortunately, this does not fix the invisible date picker.  Do I need to add the jQuery library as well?

Comment: I notice that my install of ECF7 already contains the z-index setting of 99 and the important pragma.  Do I need to point my theme to the jquery UI install path?

Answer (score 1):

Contact form 7 uses HTML5 for this, functions like Datepicker are not supported by some browsers. The following answer is from the FAQ page http://contactform7.com/faq/

> Does Contact Form 7 support HTML5 input types?
>
> Yes. Contact Form 7 3.4 and higher support form-tags corresponding to
>   these HTML5 input types: email, tel, url, number, range and date.
>
> If you don’t wish to use HTML5 input types, you can disable this by
>   adding the following code into your theme’s functions.php file: 1
>
> add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5', '__return_false' );
>
> Note that even the most current browsers partially support HTML5. For
>   example, the latest Firefox doesn’t support the date input type (that
>   allows you to choose a date from a calendar user interface) and the
>   number input type (that allows you to input a number value from a
>   spinbox UI) yet — so Firefox provides a general text input field as a
>   fallback instead of a calendar and spinbox UI. This may confuse users
>   because they can’t detect what type of input value this field expects.
>   So, you may feel that it is better to wait for all browsers to support
>   all HTML5 features completely.
>
> But you don’t need to wait! Contact Form 7 offers a better solution.
>   Contact Form 7 is able to provide jQuery UI-based fallback for the
>   date and number input fields. By using this solution, you can provide
>   calendar UI for the date field and spinbox UI for the number field,
>   respectively, even with Firefox or Internet Explorer.
>
> By default, this fallback feature is disabled because it loads extra
>   JavaScript and CSS (makes for poor performance) and it is only
>   necessary for websites that use the date or the number input fields.
>   If you use the date or number input fields and wish to use this jQuery
>   UI-based fallback feature, add the following code into your theme’s
>   functions.php file and activate the feature: 1
>
> add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' );

So in your case adding 
add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' ); 
will work if you install jquery UI, which you can find here: https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' ); this code only should be added ?

Comment: that code will only work if you have jquery UI added to your theme

Comment: do you mean jquery datepicker ?

Comment: datepicker is part of jquery UI, for install guide look at this page: https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: I have installed a jquery ui in my themes folder.

Comment: jquery needs to go in your js folder and should be added to your page, you can do this by enqueuing the .js file to your functions.php

wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array('jquery'),

Comment: I have added the jquery UI and well `add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' );` code in function.php but its not working for me

Comment: jquery appears in my folder wp-includes/js/jquery.  Is there something else which needs to be done with jquery?